# RelativeLayout doesn't meet it's on height

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

I trying to create a relative layout that look like toolbar but I keep on having such height problem as shown below:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Here's my code:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/Searchtoolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Toolbar_default_color"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/Searchtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/FilterLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/search_filter_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/search_filter_bgn_btn"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/feed_listview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FilterLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add height = 40 to  android:layout_below="@+id/Searchtoolbar" and check

Comment: @user3676184 It's not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageButton` use: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Or resize your Image using photoshop or any other free tool to fit `40dp` exactly.

> WRAP_CONTENT: which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding)

What you need:

> MATCH_PARENT: which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

[Documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Hi, I was saying the relative layout which is the white color layout as shown in the picture, not the image button...

Comment: okay did you try to make the relative layout height = wrap_content and what does it look like after changing 40 dp lets say to 20 dp because as you know dp is relative, so it different from device to another

Comment: Yes, I did try 20dp and wrap_content...
If I using 20dp, the image button will look smaller and the white layout still remain but if using wrap_content, the image button will look normal and the white layout still remain...=( 
So frustrating on this..

Answer (score 0):

I found my bad and silly mistake. It was the "android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" under the listview that causes the white layout to be extended. After I removed that line, I got what I wanted. =)